# Imagem nao aparece no projeto

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, mvc, spring

bom dia, estou tentando colocar um icone de pdf em meu projeto, porem o mesmo nao aparece. Estou utilizando o f:facet dessa forma.

```
   <h:commandLink>
       <p:graphicImage name="/resources/img/pdf.png"/>
    <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="pdf" />
   </h:commandLink>
```

a imagem esta em src/main/webapp/resources/img/pdf.png

Porem o mesmo nao renderiza na pagina

Comment: Michael, sua pergunta não está clara o suficiente, recomendo dar uma linda nesse [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) de como realizar uma pergunta válida. Abraços!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

. `JSF 2.x graphicImage`
No `JSF 2.0`, você pode renderizar a imagem acima através do conceito de "`resource library`".

```
<h:commandLink>
    <h:graphicImage library="img" name="pdf.png"/>
    <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="tbl" fileName="pdf" />
</h:commandLink>
```

https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-graphicimage-example/